# Take the nesting variables and mapping them to predicted values?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm fitting linear models for several different time periods (the example below uses countries). 
I have two questions.

Question 1: Is there a way I can pass the `mods` column to `ggpredict` without starting with `df1$mods`? something like `df1 %>% select(mods)%>% map(., ggpredict)`. I actually tried that but it doesn't work. It's not a huge deal; but I am curious.

Question 2:  Is there a way I can automate taking the names fo the grouping variable's categories and mapping them to the predicted values?

Thank you!

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(ggeffects)
 #make a fake data frame
 df1<-data.frame(country=rep(c("A", "B"), 100), var1=rnorm(200), var2=rnorm(200))
 df1
 df1 %>% 
 group_by(country) %>% 
 #in reality I have 10 to 12 variables and 1 grouping variable with 12 categories
 nest(var1, var2) %>% 
 #in reality I'm also doing glms, but I don't think it matters
 mutate(mods=map(data, function(x) lm(var1~var2, data=x))) ->out

 out$mods %>% 
 map_df(., ggpredict, terms=c('var2 [0,0.5]')) %>% 
 #Is there a way to automate this line; by taking the values of the grouping variables 
 #somehow. 
 mutate(country=rep(c('A', 'B'), each=2))
```

Comment: Have you considered using `with()`?

Comment: How would you use that?

Comment: I meant for the 1st question: `with(out, map_df(mods, ggpredict, terms = c("var2 [0,0.5]"))) `

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the attempt, but this doesn't work for me. I still get the predicted values without the grouping variable.